# Trouble adding texture to another object from texture panel

Tags: texturing, interface

(I use blender render if that is important)
I can add an image texture to an object from the texture. But when I try to do the same thing with another object, the texture panel is blank.
[image]

Comment: Going on the pic, it appears your scroll bar at right is fully down - just scroll it up  :)

Comment: @Edgel3D Yup. But I still can't add.  [link](https://imgur.com/a/zDYf59O).

Comment: Has the selected model got a material slot?  If not, give it one, then try for texture.  (Suggesting the obvious 'cos I've got little to go on)

Comment: @Edgel3D Yay, it worked. Appreciate it. Btw I didn't have to go and add a material slot for the first object.

Comment: I've noted that occasionally, if I select an object and go straight to it's texture properties, I can end up with a blank, and it happened again recently. I make it a habit of selecting the material icon 1st, then the texture to avoid this. (using vers 2.77a)  Glad to hear your problem is no more...